# Simple way to keep a Python script running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a simple script to stay running in the background. It currently looks like this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    keyboard.wait('q')
    keyboard.send('ctrl+6')
```

Now, this works already (When q is pressed, it also presses ctrl+6), but I guess there has to be a more efficient way of keeping a program running, so it can act on input.

I would rather not use an infinite while loop.

I'm on Windows

Thanks :)

Comment: That's, actually how it's done tho. It's the most efficient way there is. You could insert a `time.sleep(0.025)` or something similar to not hog your CPU tho (unless `keyboard.wait()` is a blocking call, then it doesn't matter. And perhaps implement a event-driven trigger so the actions isn't depending on the time between sleeps/loops *(for instance, `import select` does this)*. But a while loop is one of the most efficient ways to keep something alive while waiting for a condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

I'll also look into the select module

Answer (score 5):

You can using `nohup`

```
nohup python script.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

If you want check command is running

```
ps aux | grep script
```

```
user    5124 <- process_id  1.0  0.3 214588 13852 pts/4    Sl+  11:19   0:00 python script.py
```

Kill command is running

```
kill -9 [process_id]
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the platform you are using. In Linux from the terminal you can run your script with `&` at the end to start it as a background process:

```
python script.py &
```

You can then find your background process with:

```
ps -ef | grep script.py
```

And kill the process:

```
kill <pid number>
```

In windows, it's a bit more complex but the answer is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background).

*Note: I would add a `time.sleep(0.025)` command to your script (like mention in the comments).*

Comment: I'm on Windows. Sorry for not stating that, I edited my question.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's a section in my question answering for windows!

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for something same and landed here.
Here is another solution. Its working fine for me. Maybe useful to someone else too.

Use the -i option at the command line. Thus, if your Python script is foo.py, execute the following at the command line:

```
python -i foo.py
```